# Primitive data type variables in Java

Tags: java

Are variables of *primitive data types* in **Java** considered objects of the *wrapper class*? I am new to programming so please explain.

Comment: No. Please google "java wrapper class" and "java boxing and unboxing" for details about how wrapper classes and primitive data types are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Primitive data types (int, char, byte, double, etc.) are not objects, nor are they classes. The word 'primitive' lets you know that they are primal, more basic, than objects.

Primitive data types do not have member functions or class Constructors because they aren't classes themselves. You cannot call a function from a primitive data type. You couldn't do something like

```
double b = 5.5;
b.round();
```

There are Wrapper class Objects for each of the primitive data types. Integer is the object class for int data types. Double for doubles. etc.

These Wrapper Objects can and do have member functions and can also be created by Class Constructors:

```
Integer a = new Integer(1);
```

Also, as a sidebar, because new programmers often are confused by this: the String data type is not a primitive in Java. It is an Object, backed by an array of chars (a primitive data type). You can, however, declare a new String without using the new operator:

```
String s = "This is a string";
```

Answer (score 3):

> Are variables of primitive data types in Java considered objects of the wrapper class?

No. A variable with a primitive type is just a variable with a primitive type. They're completely unrelated to the wrapper classes.

The wrapper classes are used/necessary only when an object is needed, such as in a `List` or `Map` (etc.). In that case, we "wrap" a primitive value (like the `int` 5) in an object (like an `Integer`) so we can hold that object in the `List` or `Map`.

Nothing like that is needed with a variable (or parameter) that has a primitive type.